# How to show previous line to matching pattern with grep and not the matching line?

Tags: linux, grep, regular-expression

I know I can use `-A`, `-B` and `-C` to show surrounding lines but all of them also show the matching line. What I'm trying to make here is so, in this example file:

```
foo
bar
```

I'd be doing something like `grep <option> "bar" file` and my output should be
`foo`

*Side note*: I know the way of doing it with another `grep` or using `sed` but I would like to do it just by using one time `grep`

Comment: what if your file has two consecutive lines with `bar` ? what should it return ?

Comment: @PinkFloyd it does not, is always like that as I prepare it before to be like so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's quite a job for `sed`:

```
$ printf 'foo\nbar\n' | sed -n '$!N;/\nbar$/P;D'
foo
```

Comment: this is the only answer so far that actually answers the question that was asked.

Comment: How does this work?

Comment: @theonlygusti What's part you don't understand?

Comment: @cuonglm `'$!N;/\nbar$/P;D'`.

Comment: @theonlygusti `$!N` -> If not last line, append next line to the pattern space. So If you are in line 1, your pattern space will look like `line 1\nline2`. Then `/\nbar$/` will match if line 2 is `bar`. If yes, `P`rint line 1, then `D`elete the rest of pattern space `\nline 2`.

Answer (score 3):

yet another solution

```
grep -B 1 "bar" test | head -n 1
```

it has the advantage that you don't need any additional regexp or matching test, it is therefore more efficient but this won't work for multiple match

Answer (score 0):

You could do another grep which ignores "bar":

```
grep -B 1 "bar" test.txt | grep -v "bar"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:

```bash
grep -B 1 "bar" test | sed '/bar/d'
```